# openglでassimpを使ってマテリアル情報を取得できない原因が知りたい。

Tags: opengl

提示コードの`///`コメント部内部のコードですが`Assimp`を使って`blender`で書きだしたモデルをロードしてマテリアルを読み込みテクスチャーのパスを読み込みたいのですが`mat->GetTextureCount()`を使ってテクスチャーの数を表示されるとどの種類のテクスチャを`０`になってしまいます。これはなぜでしょうか？提示画像の通りベースカラーを設定しているのですが。

参考サイトA：https://note.com/info_/n/n1dd54ce4545b

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

###### コンソールログ

```
ああああ
0
mat->GetTextureCount() 0
mat->GetTextureCount() 0
mat->GetTextureCount() 0
mat->GetTextureCount() 0
0

0
```

###### Resource.cpp

```cpp
/*############################################################################################
# モデル　ロード
############################################################################################*/

std::unique_ptr<FrameWork::Model> FrameWork::Resource::LoadModel(const std::string path)
//std::shared_ptr<FrameWork::Model> FrameWork::Resource::LoadModel(const std::string path)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < modelList.size(); i++)
    {
        if (modelList.at(i).getPath() == path)
        {
            return std::make_unique<Model>(modelList.at(i).getMesh(), modelList.at(i).getPath());
        }
    }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    std::cout << "ああああ" << std::endl;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    Assimp::Importer importer;
    const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile(path, aiProcess_CalcTangentSpace | aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices | aiProcess_SortByPType | aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_FlipUVs);
    if (scene == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "ロード出来ません　" <<path << std::endl;
    }
    ProcessNode(scene->mRootNode, scene);   
    modelList.push_back(Model(meshes, path));
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    std::cout << "importer.GetErrorString() " << importer.GetErrorString() << std::endl;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    return std::make_unique<Model>(meshes, path);
}

/*############################################################################################
# ノードのメッシュを取得
############################################################################################*/
void FrameWork::Resource::ProcessNode(aiNode* node, const aiScene* scene)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < node->mNumMeshes; i++)
    {
        aiMesh* mesh = scene->mMeshes[node->mMeshes[i]];
        meshes.push_back(ProcessMesh(mesh, scene));
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < node->mNumChildren; i++)
    {
        ProcessNode(node->mChildren[i], scene);
    }
}

/*############################################################################################
# メッシュを取得
############################################################################################*/
FrameWork::Mesh FrameWork::Resource::ProcessMesh(aiMesh* mesh, const aiScene* scene)
{
    std::vector<VertexAttribute> vertices;
    std::vector<unsigned int> indices;

    std::vector<Texture> textures;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < mesh->mNumVertices; i++)
    {
        VertexAttribute vertex;

        vertex.position[0] = mesh->mVertices[i].x;
        vertex.position[1] = mesh->mVertices[i].y;
        vertex.position[2] = mesh->mVertices[i].z;

        //テクスチャ座標があるかどうか？
        if (mesh->mTextureCoords[0] != nullptr)
        {
            vertex.uv[0] = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].x;
            vertex.uv[1] = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][i].y;
        }
        else
        {
            vertex.uv[0] = 0.0f;
            vertex.uv[1] = 0.0f;
        }

        vertices.push_back(vertex);
    }

    //インデックス
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < mesh->mNumFaces; i++)
    {
        aiFace face = mesh->mFaces[i];
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < face.mNumIndices; j++)
        {
            indices.push_back(face.mIndices[j]);
        }
    }


    // process materials
    aiMaterial* material = scene->mMaterials[mesh->mMaterialIndex];
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
    std::cout <<"mesh->mMaterialIndex "<< mesh->mMaterialIndex << std::endl;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //ベースカラー
    std::vector<Texture> baseColor = LoadMaterialTextures(material, aiTextureType::aiTextureType_BASE_COLOR);
    textures.insert(textures.end(), baseColor.begin(), baseColor.end());

    std::cout << textures.size() << std::endl;
    return FrameWork::Mesh(vertices, indices, textures);
}

/*############################################################################################
# メッシュのテクスチャをロード
############################################################################################*/
std::vector<FrameWork::Texture> FrameWork::Resource::LoadMaterialTextures(aiMaterial* mat, aiTextureType type)
{
    std::vector<FrameWork::Texture> textures;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    std::cout << "mat->GetTextureCount() " << mat->GetTextureCount(aiTextureType::aiTextureType_BASE_COLOR) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "mat->GetTextureCount() " << mat->GetTextureCount(aiTextureType::aiTextureType_AMBIENT) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "mat->GetTextureCount() " << mat->GetTextureCount(aiTextureType::aiTextureType_NONE) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "mat->GetTextureCount() " << mat->GetTextureCount(aiTextureType::aiTextureType_UNKNOWN) << std::endl;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < mat->GetTextureCount(type); i++)
    {
        aiString str;
        mat->GetTexture(type, i, &str);

        bool skip = false;
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < textures_loaded.size(); j++)
        {
            if(std::strcmp(textures_loaded[j].getPath().data(), str.C_Str()) == 0)
            {
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                std::cout <<"str.C_Str() "<< str.C_Str() << std::endl;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                textures.push_back(textures_loaded[j]);
                skip = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (skip == false)
        {
            FrameWork::Texture texture(LoadTexture(str.C_Str(),type));
            textures_loaded.push_back(texture);
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            std::cout << "texture path: " << str.C_Str() << std::endl;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        }
    }

    return textures;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

以下のように列挙体全体をループしたところ`aiTextureType::aiTextureType_DIFFUSE`のところで１という結果が返ってきたのでそもそもベースカラーのテクスチャではないということがわかりました。

###### 対処方法

diffuseテクスチャでした。

```
for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "mat->GetTextureCount() " << mat->GetTextureCount((aiTextureType)i) << std::endl;
    }


    std::cout << "mat->GetTextureCount() " << mat->GetTextureCount(aiTextureType::aiTextureType_DIFFUSE) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "mat->GetTextureCount() " << mat->GetTextureCount(aiTextureType::aiTextureType_BASE_COLOR) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "mat->GetTextureCount() " << mat->GetTextureCount(aiTextureType::aiTextureType_AMBIENT) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "mat->GetTextureCount() " << mat->GetTextureCount(aiTextureType::aiTextureType_NONE) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "mat->GetTextureCount() " << mat->GetTextureCount(aiTextureType::aiTextureType_UNKNOWN) << std::endl;
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```